# Select2 Formatting result properly from Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

i'm using Select2 and this is my script, i'm wondering how to properly format the result of my server side call with the output expected for the dropdown of select2

```
 var EntitySelect = function (SelectorID, Action, Param) {
    $(SelectorID).select2({
    placeholder: "Cerca",
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    ajax: {
        type: "POST",
        url: Action,
        data: function (term, page) {
            Param.sSearch = term;
            return {                     
                     sColumns : Param.sColumns,
                     sSearch : Param.sSearch, 
                     sEntity: Param.sEntity,
                     sId: Param.sId,
            }
        },
        results: function (data) {
            return {results: data};
        },
    },
});
```

My  Server side response is that, an array of array. I want to map first value (the id) and the second one that's the option text.

```
0: [1, "Aliquam Ultrices Consulting"]
1: [2, "Congue In Scelerisque Foundation"]
2: [3, "Arcu Vestibulum LLC"]
3: [4, "Sed Inc."]
4: [5, "Lectus Associates"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this, is the solution, using the function Jquery Map
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

```
var EntitySelect = function (SelectorID, Action, Param) {
    $(SelectorID).select2({
    placeholder: "Cerca",
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    ajax: {
        type: "POST",
        url: Action,
        data: function (term, page) {
            Param.sSearch = term;
            return {                     
                     sColumns : Param.sColumns,
                     sSearch : Param.sSearch, 
                     sEntity: Param.sEntity,
                     sId: Param.sId,
            }
        },
        results: function (data) {
            var selectobj = $.map(data, function (v) {
                return {"text":v[1],"id":v[0]}
            })
            console.log(selectobj)
            return { results: selectobj };
        },
    },
    dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop", // apply css that makes the dropdown taller
});
```